# Apache Flink: The execution environment and multiple sink

Tags: java, apache-flink

My question might cause some confusion so please see Description first. It might be helpful to identify my problem. I will add my Code later at the end of the question (Any suggestions regarding my code structure/implementation is also welcomed). 
**Thank you for any help in advance!**

**My question:**

1. How to define multiple sinks in Flink Batch processing without having it get data from one source repeatedly?
2. What is the difference between `createCollectionEnvironment()` and `getExecutionEnvironment()` ? Which one should I use in local environment?
3. What is the use of `env.execute()`? My code will output the result without this sentence. if I add this sentence it will pop an Exception:

-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No new data sinks have been defined since the last execution. The last execution refers to the latest call to 'execute()', 'count()', 'collect()', or 'print()'. 
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.createProgramPlan(ExecutionEnvironment.java:940) 
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.createProgramPlan(ExecutionEnvironment.java:922) 
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.CollectionEnvironment.execute(CollectionEnvironment.java:34) 
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:816) 
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:114)
```

**Description:**
New to programming. Recently I need to process some data (grouping data, calculating standard deviation, etc.) using Flink Batch processing.
However I came to a point where I need to output two DataSet. 
The structure was something like this

> From Source(Database) -> DataSet 1 (add index using zipWithIndex())-> DataSet 2  (do some calculation while keeping index) -> DataSet 3

First I output `DataSet 2`, the index is e.g. from 1 to 10000;
And then I output `DataSet 3` the index becomes from 10001 to 20000 although I did not change the value in any function.
My guessing is when outputting `DataSet 3` instead of using the result of 
previously calculated `DataSet 2` it started from getting data from database again and then perform the calculation.
With the use of `ZipWithIndex()` function it does not only give the wrong index number but also increase the connection to db.

I guess that this is relevant to the execution environment, as when I use

> ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.createCollectionsEnvironment();

will give the "wrong" index number (10001-20000)
and

> ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

will give the correct index number (1-10000)
The time taken and number of database connections is different and the order of print will be reversed.

**OS, DB, other environment details and versions:**
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.5 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-173.4674.33, built on March 6, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b15 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

**My Test code(Java)：**

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.createCollectionsEnvironment();

```
    //Table is used to calculate the standard deviation as I figured that there is no such calculation in DataSet.
    BatchTableEnvironment tableEnvironment = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);

    //Get Data from a mySql database
    DataSet<Row> dbData =
            env.createInput(
                    JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
                            .setDrivername("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
                            .setDBUrl($database_url)
                            .setQuery("select value from $table_name where id =33")
                            .setUsername("username")
                            .setPassword("password")
                            .setRowTypeInfo(new RowTypeInfo(BasicTypeInfo.DOUBLE_TYPE_INFO))
                            .finish()
            );

    // Add index for assigning group (group capacity is 5)
    DataSet<Tuple2<Long, Row>> indexedData = DataSetUtils.zipWithIndex(dbData);

    // Replace index(long) with group number(int), and convert Row to double at the same time
    DataSet<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> rawData = indexedData.flatMap(new GroupAssigner());

    //Using groupBy() to combine individual data of each group into a list, while calculating the mean and range in each group
    //put them into a POJO named GroupDataClass
    DataSet<GroupDataClass> groupDS = rawData.groupBy("f0").combineGroup(new GroupCombineFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Double>, GroupDataClass>() {
        @Override
        public void combine(Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> iterable, Collector<GroupDataClass> collector) {
            Iterator<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> it = iterable.iterator();
            Tuple2<Integer, Double> var1 = it.next();
            int groupNum = var1.f0;

            // Using max and min to calculate range, using i and sum to calculate mean
            double max = var1.f1;
            double min = max;
            double sum = 0;
            int i = 1;

            // The list is to store individual value
            List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(max);

            while (it.hasNext())
            {
                double next = it.next().f1;
                sum += next;
                i++;
                max = next > max ? next : max;
                min = next < min ? next : min;
                list.add(next);
            }

            //Store group number, mean, range, and 5 individual values within the group
            collector.collect(new GroupDataClass(groupNum, sum / i, max - min, list));
        }
    });

    //print because if no sink is created, Flink will not even perform the calculation.
    groupDS.print();


    // Get the max group number and range in each group to calculate average range
    // if group number start with 1 then the maximum of group number equals to the number of group
    // However, because this is the second sink, data will flow from source again, which will double the group number
    DataSet<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> rangeDS = groupDS.map(new MapFunction<GroupDataClass, Tuple2<Integer, Double>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer, Double> map(GroupDataClass in) {
            return new Tuple2<>(in.groupNum, in.range);
        }
    }).max(0).andSum(1);

    // collect and print as if no sink is created, Flink will not even perform the calculation.
    Tuple2<Integer, Double> rangeTuple = rangeDS.collect().get(0);
    double range = rangeTuple.f1/ rangeTuple.f0;
    System.out.println("range = " + range);
}

public static class GroupAssigner implements FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Long, Row>, Tuple2<Integer, Double>> {
    @Override
    public void flatMap(Tuple2<Long, Row> input, Collector<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> out) {

        // index 1-5 will be assigned to group 1, index 6-10 will be assigned to group 2, etc.
        int n = new Long(input.f0 / 5).intValue() + 1;
        out.collect(new Tuple2<>(n, (Double) input.f1.getField(0)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. It's fine to connect a source to multiple sink, the source gets executed only once and records get broadcasted to the multiple sinks. See this question [Can Flink write results into multiple files (like Hadoop's MultipleOutputFormat)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067959/can-flink-write-results-into-multiple-files-like-hadoops-multipleoutputformat)
2. `getExecutionEnvironment` is the right way to get the environment when you want to run your job. `createCollectionEnvironment` is a good way to play around and test. See the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/local_execution.html#collection-environment)
3. The exception error message is very clear: if you call print or collect your data flow gets executed. So you have two choices:

- Either you call print/collect at the end of your data flow and it gets executed and printed. That's good for testing stuff. Bear in mind you can only call collect/print once per data flow, otherwise it gets executed many time while it's not completely defined
- Either you add a sink at the end of your data flow and call env.execute(). That's what you want to do once your flow is in a more mature shape.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't understand your reply at the first time. Your reply is very helpful! By the way can I write a sink that perform in the same way as collect? Thank you again!